# How to keep only required options in adobe creative sdk

Tags: android, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I am using adobe creative sdk in my application. But my app needs only **draw** and **text** option. So is there way to remove other image editing options from the bottom bar.? If my question is too broad please let me know I'll update the question.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a way to customize the Tool List in the Creative SDK Image Editor.

Below, I'll give you a quick overview, then link you to a blog post where you can get more details.

## Overview

**Creating your tool list**
You can create a list of the tools you require with the `ToolLoaderFactory.Tools` enum:

```
ToolLoaderFactory.Tools[] mTools = {ToolLoaderFactory.Tools.DRAW, ToolLoaderFactory.Tools.TEXT};
```

We'll use this array in the next step.

**Using your tool list**

The array you made above can now be passed into your `AdobeImageIntent.Builder()` chain, using the `withToolList()` method:

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
    .setData(uri) // input image src
    .withToolList(mTools)
    .build();
```

Only the tools passed to `withToolList()` will appear in the Image Editor, giving you control over which tools your users have access to.

## Further reading

For a deeper dive into customizing the tool list in the Creative SDK Image Editor, [see this post on the Creative SDK blog](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2015/10/customizing-the-image-editor-tools-android/).

Comment: SO says "Avoid Thanks or +1" in comments.. But how can I appreciate a guy who solved my problem by just giving +25 credits.. Nah.. I have to say thanks atleast.. Thanks @Ash Ryan.. It helped..